# getting a button name or value to the js function that contains a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

Hi I'm new to `Javascript` and trying to send a value calculated with `PHP` to a `JS` function by retrieving either the value or the name of the clicked button.

**the PHP file:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/script.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="500" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"><strong>#</strong></td>
        <td width="30%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
        <td width="10%"><strong>Price</strong></td>
        <td width="10%" align="center" colspan="3"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
$shopgold = $userRow['gold']; 
$pricegold = 255; 
$maxkopengold = $shopgold / $pricegold;
?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="metals/gold.png" width="100%"></td>
        <td>Gold</td>
        <td><?php echo $pricegold; ?></td>
        <td><button name="goldValue" onClick="countDownGold()" value="<?php echo $maxkopengold; ?>">-</button></td>
        <td align="center">(<span id="goldValue">0</span>/<?php echo $maxkopengold; ?>)</td>
        <td><button name="goldValueUp" onClick="countUpGold()" value="<?php echo $maxkopengold; ?>">+</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/script.js**

```
function countUpGold() {
    var currentVal = document.getElementById("goldValue").innerHTML;
    var maxVal = jQuery(this).attr("name");
    var elements = document.getElementsByName ("goldValueUp");
        newVal = currentVal;
        alert(this.value);
        newVal++;
    if (currentVal < maxVal) {
        newVal++;
    }
    document.getElementById("goldValue").innerHTML = newVal;
}
function countDownGold() {
    var currentVal = document.getElementById("goldValue").innerHTML;
        addVal = 1;
        var newVal = 0;
    if (currentVal > 0) {
        newVal = currentVal - addVal;
    }
    document.getElementById("goldValue").innerHTML = newVal;
}
```

I got the `+` and `-` button working but now I'm trying to set a maximum of (available money / price of object) and is then set to a `PHP` variable that will be used as name or value of the button. like `buttonname.value`

I hope i'm making sense. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to `window` object in the inline click handler, thus `jQuery(this).attr("name")` will not work. You need to pass the current element context i.e. `this` to inline click handler.

```
<button name="goldValueUp" onClick="countUpGold(this)" value="<?php echo $maxkopengold; ?>">+</button>
```

and use it

```
function countUpGold(elem) {
    var maxVal = elem.getAttribute('name'); //jQuery(elem).attr("name");
    var value = elem.value;
    //Your existing code
}
```

---

However as you are using jQuery, I would recommend to use unobtrusive event handler. Assign a common class i.e. `goldValueUp` then bind event handler using it.

*HTML*

```
<button name="goldValueUp" class="goldValueUp" value="<?php echo $maxkopengold; ?>">+</button>
```

*Script*

```
$(function(){
    $('.goldValueUp').on('click', function(){
        var maxVal = jQuery(elem).attr("name");
        //Some operations
    })
})
```